# Replace keywords in dataframe column using pandas dictionary

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe that contain 4 columns, one of them is called action_description, it contain "free text" that resume the different actions done to resolve an issue.

The words in this column are sometimes miswritting, and we have a dictionnary, for all famous miswords (example: REPLCD -> REPLACED, .....)

I want to replace all miswords in my column using python code.

Here's the code I use:

Code:

```
import sys
import pyspark
import pandas_datareader
import re
import csv
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
from pandas import *

xls = ExcelFile("test_doc_2.xls")
df = xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[0])
df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1]],inplace=True,axis=1)
df2 = Series(df.TO_VALUE.values,index=df.FROM_VALUE).to_dict()

xls1 = ExcelFile("Test_Source_New_2.xls")
df1 = xls1.parse(xls1.sheet_names[0])

df1['WORK_PERFORMED_NEW'] = df1['WORK_PERFORMED'].replace(df2, regex=True)
```

This solution work, except in some cases,

in my dictionary: DEF -> DEFERRED, DEFERED -> DEFERRED

so with my solution: DEFERED -> DEFERREDERED, at it replaced DEF in DEFERED by DEFERRED and it got concatenated with ERED, DEFERRED+ERED.

I thought about using boundaries (r"\b"), but I got syntax error !!!

How can I overcome this issue .

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue you are facing is due to regex = True. As you mentioned you have a dictionary:

```
DEF -> DEFERRED, DEFERED -> DEFERRED
```

So,when you pass **DEF**ERED , it first finds **DEF** and replaces it with **DEFERRED** in place followed by **ERED**. So you will get:

```
DEFERED -> DEFERREDERED
```

Simplified:

```
DEF +ERED -> DEFERRED + ERED -> DEFFEREDERED
```

In case of any query, you can comment.

Comment: would like to suggest a solution as well. Issue with code has already been explained by OP

Comment: I think I found a solution, is to add first the \\b to my dictionary, and then use it.

Comment: like this: 

df3 = {r'(\b){}(\b)'.format(k):r'\1{}\2'.format(v) for k,v in df2.items()}

df1['WORK_PERFORMED_NEW'] = df1['WORK_PERFORMED'].replace(df3, regex=True)

Comment: If the words are separate , use regex = False, so it will check for that exact word and then only it would replace.

Comment: Cool. \b would also perform the same thing. It will check for word only.

Comment: you solution, worked too, thank you very much, if I put regex=False, does it mean, that I can't inlude any regex expressions in my formula ?

Comment: @Mouad : Yes, If you want to put a regex pattern, you will have to mention regex = True. But, in your case you are checking specific words, not a pattern. So, it works.

Comment: Hello, your solution works when I want to replace one word from my 1st column (from_value) with the matching word from the (to_value) column, but if for example my first word is a 2 string word : for example ALT BRK -> ALTERNATE BREAK, and I have other rows with : ALT -> ALTERNATIVE, BRK -> BREAK, if in my sentence I have ALT BRK, it convert each word with the rules given in the separate rows, which is incorrect in my case, how can I include this case ? thanks

Comment: @Mouad: I'll have to chk for it.If you could post or forward me a sample data frame of df1 and df2. I can check for the possible solution.

Comment: how can I forward it to you ? (I have a limitation restraint for posting), I can't post anything for 2 days.

Comment: You can upload sample file on Gdrive and share the link here.

Comment: here's the link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HYFhKAqbYPIy0ekyj9xLSbk30YZwf8ZG?usp=sharing , I put the 2 samples (excel files), for the df2 file (subtitution file, just a clarification, when we have some special character, % , ! .., we remove them, except for same cases, when for example the "/" is used inside a word (well, if it's not clear, just let me know), thanks in advance.

Comment: If possible, you can maintain two separate dictionaries. First passing through the dictionary that contains multiple words and then passing it through the dictionary containing single words. or another possible option is a rule-based approach. i.e you can define certain rules for applying regex.

Comment: well, for the 1st solution I don't think it will be possible, because I'll need to maintain one source file, unless if I'll have the possibilities to create 2 dictionnaries while keeping one source file, by creating a method or a function that loop on each row and see if the from-value contain more than one word or not,  as per your second option, I'm not sure to fully understand, can you rexplain ?

Comment: @Mouad: Rule based approach would take much time. So leave it for now. you can try to store keys having multiple words as word1\s+word2. Then chk for the same.

Comment: I succeded to find the good condition to separate my first dataframe into 2 dataframe, but I'm not able to find the appropriate function to parse my dataset and append the rows in the new dataframe, here's the function I use to determine whether I have 1 word or more:         for elem in df2['FROM_VALUE']:
 
if len(elem.split()) > 1:   ## i want to append data in the dataframe for more than 1 word    , else: the other data frame , do you have an idea what function to use , for information, I'm using pandas dataframe ,  to read the excel file for the subsitution table and create the dataframe

Comment: @Sam: i got a partial solution for splitting the data into 2 dataframes, but I have an issue when trying to replace the original words that contain special character by the "TO_value", I got some errors, is there a way to force python to replace whenever he finds the special character with the given value according to our table (for example 1-APU -> 1 APU, or to replace special character with empty value), ...

Comment: @Mouad: Do you want to remove all special characters or specific characters between the words you want to replace? 
One solution is to replace all special characters with space using this regex:- import re   re.sub("([^A-Za-z0-9])"," ",text) where text is your row and then use it.You will have to use .loc for this and apply lambda function on dataframe. I would suggest you to frame a new question accordingly and post it instead of asking it in comments. There is a better chance of getting the solution in that way.